# A responsive slick slider inside iMac

Tags: javascript, jquery, slick.js

I'm using slick slider. I want to make a slider inside an iMac png picture. Cant do the right way to responsive it and make it roll inside that png pic. Please help to correct that. This is my [example](https://jsfiddle.net/059tmowq/1/):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery(".mac-slider").slick({
    centerMode: true,
    centerPadding: '60px'
  });
});
```

Comment: do you really think there is something special about sliders "inside an iMac"? it's way more important what browser you use, not which type of computer hardware you have.

Comment: @low_rents I mean inside an iMac picture))

Answer (score 0):

You can set static width and height of your image to fit into iMac screen and position using `position: relative`.

```
html, body{
  height: 100%; /* Body and html need to have 100% height in order to show whole background image */
}

.mac-slider {
  background-image: url('http://www.cincinnatiskinandlaser.com/wp-content/plugins/wp-graphic/templates/video/imac/images/testi_bg.png');
  background-position: top center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 100%; /* This also needs to have 100% height in order to show whole background image */
}

.mac-slider-item img {
  margin: 27px auto;
  opacity: 0.3;
}

.slick-current img {
  opacity: 1 !important;
  position: relative; /* Position of current image centered in iMac screen */
  left: 2px;
  top: -9px;
}

.slick-slide img{
  width: 467px; /* Static dimensions of picture to fit into iMac screen */
  height: 263px;
}
```

Comment: the main problem is that the slides must roll under the monitor.